# Initial transform in runtime angular cdk drag and drop

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

How can I initial transform in run time ?
I try to position the element on start but it not working.
I try to had it to the css file like this:

```
transform: translate3d(-361px, -1252px, 0px);
```

its work on initial but when I drag the element its reset to the original position of the cdk.

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution.

```
<div class="partner-signature" *ngIf="isPartnerSignature" cdkDragBoundary=".pdf-file" [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="elementPosition" cdkDrag>

export class SignatureVerificationStageComponent implements OnChanges {

elementPosition: { x: number; y: number; };

constructor(private _fileService: FileService) {
 this.elementPosition = { x: -361, y: -1252 };
   }
}
```